# Le mot anagramme

Tags: usage

Dénombrer toutes les anagrammes possibles du mot PRISÉE

1. En tenant compte de l’accent
2. En ne tenant pas compte de l’accent sur le "e" .

Le mot anagramme est-il un mot reconnu ? Peut-on l'utiliser couramment (niveau post-bac) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je dirais que le mot est relativement connu.

Certains pourraient peut-être être tentés de restreindre les anagrammes aux mots qui ont un sens<sup>1</sup>, ceux qui sont dans le dictionnaire mais je ne pense pas qu'il y en ait beaucoup après un bac scientifique.

Autre chose, beaucoup de gens pensent qu'anagramme est un mot masculin, probablement parce qu'on dit *un gramme*, pas *une gramme*.

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>Voir réponse d'Yttria dans https://www.jeuxvideo.com/forums/1-35-8947352-1-0-1-0-bts-nombre-d-anagramme-d-un-mot.htm</sub>

Comment: Il est vrai que plusieurs noms en *-gramme* sont masculins : *télégramme*, *programme*, *chronogramme*.

Comment: @XouDo Oui, seuls deux mots en -gramme sur trente-sept sont féminins, *épigramme* et *anagramme*. Le genre d'épigramme est lui aussi source d'erreurs.